# I don't get a password prompt on Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Two days ago, my Surface Pro 3 overheated and turned off. I was already getting errors for apps I use commonly, such as Word, and my computer was also updating around that time. When I had cooled my PC down from the overheat, I turns it on. However, on my lock screen, there's no password prompt box, nor there was my username and image. It was blank. On the side I still have the Network, Ease of Access and Power buttons, however no prompt. Also, my PC picked up no networks. I tried to boot it into safe mode and other shortcuts such as Ctrl+Alt+Del, however to no avail. I then went into the Setup menu, however I couldn't find out what to do. Apparently, it's a known issue, however I can't fix it. Help?

Comment: Repair your OS using Media

Comment: @TechieGossip - How do you do that? Does it take away any information?